# How to scale one face of a skewed cube in the same skewed axis

Tags: scale, transform-orientation

I am trying to follow a book on using blender (Blender 3d by Example), however I cannot seem to achieve the same result when following the steps exactly. What I want to end up with is the picture below. I have a skewed cube, with one face extruded and then scaled down but only parallel to the skewed side. The book however, uses the S + Z key combo for this. But this essentially moves the top and bottom edge up and down in a straight line.So I want the scaling to happen as in the example below. Please note that in the example image, I've tried to achieve the same by extruding first and then moving the edges into their skewed position. But this seems cumbersome. In real situations, the object I'm working on may have been skewed already.
Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit hard to tell what you want the end result to be, but I think you can get what you want by selecting the face, right clicking, and choosing "extrude faces along normals".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, Sorry, I noticed that my images changed their position. I've fixed that now and added some extra clarification on what I want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, ok. I know what you mean, but I don't know how to do it. There are always workarounds though. When you plan to scale it, do you want the result to be "larger" or smaller on the Z axis than the face itself?

Comment: I'd like them to be smaller, so that I can extrude multiple faces where each one is a little bit smaller than the previous one.

Comment: What I recommend you do then, is extrude the face by whatever distance you want, then select the top and bottom edges individually, and slide them on the face by pressing g + g. You can slide by number increment < 1 (ex g, g, .3) if you want to keep things constant. Once you have both the edges "slid", select the center of the "new" face and move it along the X axis.  - It's dirty I know, but it's the best I can think of until someone else comes along with a better answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could extrude and scale the faces while the object is still "upright", and then tilt them all together using proportional edit.

Comment: Thanks all for your contribution. I've now learned multiple ways to achieve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change *Pivot Point* - **Individual Origins**
- Select skewed (side) edges only
- *Scale*

[image]

To move this selection in the skew direction change *Transform Orientation* > **Normal**
and move <kbd>G</kbd> in <kbd>Y</kbd> axis.

[image]
(*Thanks Robin Betts for extension.*)

Comment: Maybe you could add, if in 'Normal' Orientation, with the same selection, GY will move the  pair of edges along themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have no idea how the book author could have possibly accomplished this by just trying to scale the face itself in the Z direction since the Z axis doesn't skew along with the rest. But this works so thanks again!

Comment: I would like to know as well  i dont have the book, but if it Is not explained clearly, you can contact author to improve that part.

Comment: @RobinBetts Ah, sorry it took me a time to understand what do you mean :) I hope its correct. Its just weird a gizmo didnt change in that direction, hm ... thanks

Comment: Hmmmm, too! My move Gizmo shows Y parallel to the edges... but I reset my pivot to Median.. I just tried it again, and with Individual Origins, the edges were sent in opposite directions.. sorry, should have mentioned that, I do things unconsciously.